# Clustering file and ftp/sftp endpoints in camel/service mix

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I have a scenario which I would like to understand and learn when  run two service mix instances in different box .Each instance has a same program which will take a file from a ftp endpoint. How will they behavior be .

Will both the nodes pick the file or only one picks it. In this case we are not deleting the file after the read or moving the file to any other location and the file remains for a longer time.

I would also like to know if there are any load balancing solution available for this scenario that can be configured from  Camel for the the inbound endpoint like file and ftp/sftp.

Comment: FTP/SFTP allows multiple users to download the same file. So in your case both routes can and probably will download the same file again. I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you need to download the files in parallel? What is the reason for clustering/load balancing?

Comment: @Namphibian - I wanted to have two instances in a clustered/load balancing is because a stage where that will be large application and the number of applications is huge and in addition if it handles messages of large size, then we will need a scalable architecture.While we are building a complete open source environment we have to personally take care of the load balancing and clustering .Each of these endpoints behave differently and needs separate solution in such environment.In higher environments(Pre-Prod and Prod) we need more than 2 nodes with the servicemix instance.Thus this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache ServiceMix does not have such functionality.

fabric8 has this out of the box with the Camel master component

- http://fabric8.io/#/site/book/doc/index.md?chapter=camelEndpointMaster_md

Though you can take a look at using route policy with Apache Camel

- http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy

... where there is a zookeeper route policy for master/failover. But

- http://camel.apache.org/zookeeper

... or you can build your custom route policy to do master/failover also.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to make the above scenario with the service mix?